# $.each() loop not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Ajax_GetCartOrders","Business")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(email),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) 
                    {

                            alert("success"); // this works
                            alert(result);    //this works and shows the correct data

                            $.each(result, function () 
                            {
                               alert("inside loop");// this doesnt work
                            });
                    },
```

Why doesnt the alert inside $.each work ?
The sucess alert works and the alert result displays the right json data

```
 result data

    {"id":6,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},       {"id":7,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":8,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":9,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":10,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":11,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":12,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":19,"email":"TEST","date":"TEST","relation":"TEST"},{"id":3,"email":"testemail","date":null,"relation":null}]
```

Comment: It seems like there a missing  `[` in the beginning, anyway is result a string or an object?

Comment: You need to convert your 'result' from json to an actual array in order for the code to work. You can use JSON.parse for this. The each function requires a collection object

Comment: @ChetterHummin: The `ajax` method does that when you specify the data type as json.

Comment: @Guffa I was not aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: $.parseJSON fixed it. thanks

Comment: @Spungey If you found a fix, can you add it as an answer please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$(result).each(function(){
    console.log(this.email);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22BBv/